# Unable to filter results successfully if using OR inside NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a NSArray & i am trying to filter results based on below mentioned Query :

```
self->filteredValues =
        [self->AllValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.sku contains[cd]%@",text]];
```

I am able to successfully filter results if i use SELF.sku or SELF.name separately.

Issue is when i use OR between the query  like this ,i got the crash result:

```
 self->filteredValues =
        [self->AllValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.sku contains[cd]%@) OR (SELF.name contains[cd]%@)",text]];
```

> Error : 2018-06-05 12:39:55.137706+0530 AppName[43371:14206450] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't look for value
>   () in string (24" NOBLE WREATH (6));
>   value is not a string '

How to resolve this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There second argument is missing in predicate.

```
self->filteredValues =
    [self->AllValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.sku contains[cd]%@) OR (SELF.name contains[cd]%@)",text, <#second argument#>]];
```

Set `<#second argument#>` in predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Check the predicate's format string. You have two `%@` placeholders but only one argument providing value.

I bet this will fix the issue:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.sku contains[cd]%@) OR (SELF.name contains[cd]%@)", text, text]
```